# Mysql RAM requirement for 22 Billion Records Select query

Tags: mysql

I have a table which is expected to have 22 billion records yearly. How much will be the RAM requirement if each of the records cost around 4 KB of data.

It is expected to have around 8 TB of storage for the same table.

**[update]**
There is no join queries involved. I just need the select queries to be executed efficiently.

Comment: That depends enormously on the queries involved, the indexes in place, and a variety of other such things. You'll may also wind up complicating stuff a bit with sharding etc.

Comment: @ceejayoz, yeah, but i just want to know how much ram is required to execute the select query efficiently without performance issue. so i can plan accordingly with other query's in a proportion.

Comment: That can't be answered with the information you've given. It depends on the queries involved, and the indexes, and a bunch of other things. Your question, as it stands, is like saying "how fast can a car go" without specifying the type of car.

Comment: If it's analytical queries, you might want to look into MariaDB's [ColumnStore](https://mariadb.com/products/technology/columnstore) engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that there is no general rule of thumb when it comes to how much RAM you need for x amount of records in `MYSQL`.

The first factor which you need to look at is the design of the database itself. This is one of the most impacting factors of them all. If your database is poorly designed, throwing RAM at it isn't going to fix your problem.

Another factor is how this data is going to be accessed, i.e if a specific row is being accessed by 100 people `SELECT * FROM table where column = value` then you could get away with a tiny amount of `RAM` as you would just use query caching.

It `MAY` (not always) be a good idea to keep your entire database in `RAM` to allow it to be read quicker (Dependent on the total size of the database). I.e. if your database is 100GB in size then 128GB of RAM should be proficient to deal with any overheads such as the OS and other factors.

Comment: thanks Lewis Browne, I agree caching is good way when we are repeatedly using same query in short span of time. But can you explain how this RAM is gonna affect the performance of the system? considering there is no complex indexing in table and no join queries planned. just the select query has to be done. Is there any proportion in amount of RAM we need to use for handling such big amount of data ? it will be an InnoDB

Comment: As i said previously, i don't think there is real rule of thumb when it comes to allocating memory. If I were you, Dependent on the total size of the database in `GB` i would consider putting the entire database in ram, and then adding extra for any overhead.

For example. If your DB is 100GB then go with 128GB.

Answer (score -1):

As per my system i am supporting daily Oracle 224GB CDR record to a network operator.
Also for another system daily 20 lack data retrieve from SQL database .

```
you can use 128 GB if you are using one server or else 
if you are using load balancer then you can use 62 GB on every PC.
```

Comment: Please share the DB Server name eg. Mysql, SQL Server, Oracle, Mongo DB

Comment: Hi Fahad, the DB Server is MySQL